# .NET events - blocking subscribers from subscribing on an event

Tags: c#, events, hook, overriding, subscribe

Let's say I have a "Processor" interface exposing an event - OnProcess. Usually the implementors do the processing. Thus I can safely subscribe on this event and be sure it will be fired. But one processor doesn't do processing - thus I want to prevent subscribers to subscibe on it. Can I do that? In other words in the code below I want the last line to throw an exception:

```
var emptyProcessor = new EmptyProcessor();
emptyProcessor.OnProcess += event_handler; // This line should throw an exception.
```

Comment: Imagine you were the person assigned to find out why code crashes. Would you look for error at this line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class EmptyProcessor : IProcessor {

    [Obsolete("EmptyProcessor.OnProcess should not be directly accessed", true)]
    public event EventHandler OnProcess { 
        add { throw new NotImplementedException(" :( "); }
        remove { }
    }
}
```

In this situation, the `true` parameter on Obsolete causes a compile-time exception. so:

```
EmptyProcessor processor1 = new EmptyProcessor();
IProcessor processor2 = new EmptyProcessor();

processor1.OnProcess += handler;  // <-- compile-time error
processor2.OnProcess += handler;  // <-- run-time error
```

Comment: Wow... I didn't even know you could do that. I just wrote a quick sample application to test it, and who knew... it worked. Very interesting.

Comment: +1, although I'm not sure this exception message would be very helpful ;)

Comment: I agree the idea is sloppy. But there's plenty of uses of NotSupportedException even in the BCL... but I'm firmly of the opinion that *nothing* is "considered harmful" 100% of the time, (no, not even GOTO)

Comment: `NotSupportedException` is fine. But one can hardly guess that merely subscribing to event will cause it. Imagine this code is exposed through a library. How the heck is event subscriber supposed to know that `+=` will throw an exception, especially when dealing with class through interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with custom `add`/`remove` methods but I believe this is a bad practice.

Look, you have an **interface**, a *contract* to be implemented by different classes.
`OnProcess` is part of this contract and is not special in any way.

One usually uses interfaces when she wants to **work with different classes under the same set of operations**. Interfaces allow you to code like this:

```
IProcessor proc = GetProcessorAnyhow ();
proc.DoSomething ();
```

without knowing concrete type at compile type.

However, with your approach,

```
IProcessor proc = GetProcessorAnyhow ();
proc.OnProcess += (sender, e) => { };
```

may fail without any apparent reason, although it looks like absolutely legitimate code.
**[Always make sure that wrong code *looks* wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).**

You may have done one of the following design mistakes:

- Put `OnProcess` in `IProcessor` whereas **it may not be *each* processor's contract**;
- Made `EmptyProcessor` implement `IProcessor`, whereas actually **it can't satisfy the contract**.