# Blocking event subscription in compile time

Tags: c#, events, blocking, subscriber

Related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283013/net-events-blocking-subscribers-from-subscribing-on-an-event). Is there a way to block the subscription in compile time? Something like marking the event's "Add" as "private" in the implementor even though it's public in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can define compile macros, and wrap around #if tag.

```
#if DEBUG
// do something only when we are launching Debug configuration
#endif

#if MYMACRO
// do something only when this macro is defined
#endif
```

Comment: I didn't understand how this answers my question.

Comment: You can block the subscription in compile time if you tell the compiler to omit while doing the compile. For that you use an #if block, and you make use of a macro. This way if you setup the #if correctly the code inside it won't be compiled in the exe, as it was never written there.